# why my object is sorting it's dynamic value when loop

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I have this function that assigns dynamic key to initialized object

```
function meanCluster(clusters) {
   let initialized = {};

   clusters.forEach(mean => {
      initialized[mean] = [];
   })

   return initialized;
}
```

and I have these data

```
const OneDimensionPoint = [22, 9, 12, 15, 10, 27, 35, 18, 36, 11]
```

now I want to assign element 22, 9, and 12 as the key to my initialized variable inside my meanCluster function and to do that my approach is this code below.

```
let mean = [OneDimensionPoint[0], OneDimensionPoint[1], OneDimensionPoint[2]]

meanCluster(mean)
```

when I console.log(meanCluster(mean)) the result is this

```
{9: Array(0), 12: Array(0), 22: Array(0)}
```

I get 9, 12, 22 as the key instead of 22, 9, 12

my object is sorted, and I don't want. I also want to keep it as Number and not string.

can someone tell me why?

Comment: What are you doing that requires them to be in a different order? Object entries are stored in alphabetical/ascending order. Also object keys are always strings.

Comment: it is needed for future calculations

Comment: Use an array if order is important.

Comment: You could also use a `Map`. It maintains insertion order, without treating numeric keys specially.

Comment: @Axekan Numeric keys are in numeric order, non-numeric keys are in insertion order. Nothing is in lexicographic order in objects.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does JavaScript guarantee object property order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525795/does-javascript-guarantee-object-property-order)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a ES6 [MAP](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map):

```js
const OneDimensionPoint = [22, 9, 12, 15, 10, 27, 35, 18, 36, 11] ;
let mean = [OneDimensionPoint[0], OneDimensionPoint[1], OneDimensionPoint[2]];

console.log(
    mean.reduce((r,i)=>{
        r.set(i,[])
        return r;
    }, new Map())
)
```